# In IE7, module not defined in require callback function

Tags: javascript, module, requirejs, frontend

I've got a pretty simple require setup in my main.js file.  This block of code with in Firefox, Chrome, and all IE 8 - 10, but in IE7, the Sitewide object is not defined on some page loads.  It's very sporadic, but half the time the alert returns "undefined" and other times "function".

Wondering if anyone has seen something like this before or can offer some suggestions?

```
// Includes File Dependencies
require([
"jquery",
"underscore",
"tipper",
"foundation_app",
"sitewide"
], function($, _, Tipper, foundation_app, Sitewide) {

    alert(typeof Sitewide);
    var sitewide = new Sitewide();

});

});
```

Comment: If it's sporadic, then most likely issue is with other code that we can not see here. Are all modules are anonymous modules? Is everything loaded asynchronously? Do you have live link?

Comment: Sure, you can take a look here: http://pc401k.authenticff.com/who-we-are -- username: personal, password: capital

Comment: Strange though that I can't get the bug to appear on the staging server, but it pops up about 50% of the time on my local VM instance where I'm testing ie7.

Comment: I see you are relying on shim a lot. It is very easy to miss a dependency, I see that there is no jquery dependency on foundation/app, so in case when dependencies load in required order it works, on you local VM because of fast network you get different loading order. Try using require, bundled with jQuery to minimize the risk of it loading too late.

Comment: Ok, I'll double check those dependancies.  What do you mean "bundled with jquery"?  Also -- Inside a module definition define(["dep1", "dep2"]) ... do those dependancies need to be defined in require.config?  For example in my Sitewide.js file where I define that module, I dont have it's dependancies inside the shim.

Comment: There used to be RequireJS version bundled with jQuery, but I see that it was removed from RequireJS documentation. Inside module definition if dependencies can be resolved automatically you don't need to configure them. If not, then you need to specify paths in the main config. I see that foundation_app invokes immediately and expects jQuery to be loaded already, but there is no  dependency specified in the shim configuration for this module. That is your problem.

Comment: The RequireJs/jQuery concatenated file is still referenced in the [documentation](http://requirejs.org/docs/jquery.html).  You can find the actual project/file [here](https://github.com/jrburke/require-jquery/blob/master/jquery-require-sample/webapp/scripts/require-jquery.js).

Answer (score 1):

You have shim configuration setup, but keep in mind that you still need to reference them as dependencies in order to be loaded properly.

Shim configuration only ensures loading order, so in you main module (or some other dependent module) specify all them as dependencies so that they are loaded by RequireJS.

Comment: Well I implemented all those changes but am still seeing the error on my local machine.  Really not sure why, but I guess I'm going to leave it for now since the development environment isn't of major concern.